# Recursividad de funciones

Tags: python

Me ayudarían a entender la recursividad? No termino de entender el flujo de esta y cómo funciona. Miré muchos videos del tema, busque información en internet y no hay caso, no puedo entenderlo.

```py
'''
 Haciendo uso de la recursividad de funciones, escriba un programa que pida un valor entero positivo n, y luego que genere todas las combinaciones posibles de las cadenas de caracteres binarias de longitud n sin que haya 2 o más números uno consecutivos.
 Ejemplo-1:
 Entrada:
    Ingrese un valor entero positivo: 4
 Salida:
    0000 0001 0010 0100 0101 1000 1001 1010
'''

def combinaciones_binarias(n, space='', last_digit=0):
    # Si el número llega a ser de n dígitos, imprimirlo.
    if n == 0:
        print(space, end=' ')
        return
 
    # Añadir 0 al resultado y repetir con un dígito menos.
    combinaciones_binarias(n - 1, space + '0', 0)
 
    # Añadir 1 al resultado y repetir con un dígito menos en caso de que el último digito es 0.
    if last_digit == 0:
        combinaciones_binarias(n - 1, space + '1', 1)
 
n = int(input('Ingrese un  número entero positivo: '))
combinaciones_binarias(n)
```

Comment: Para entender la recursividad, antes debes entender la recursividad. Mira a ver si estas respuestas mias sobre el tema te ayudan https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208154/7123 https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490630/7123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te entiendo, al principio no es fácil.
Recursividad es un concpeto parecido a un circulo vicioso:

- ¿por qué va a caballo?
- Porque es el jefe
- ¿Porqué es el Jefe?
- Porque va a caballo

Pero a diferencia de éste no se repite eternamente, llega un momento en que deja de repetirse. Más que un círculo vicioso es una "espiral viciosa". En un momento dado deja de repetirse.
Más o menos esta es la idea.
Ejemplo: ordenar una lista:

1. Sacar el elemento más grande y ordenar la lista sin ese elemento
2. Si en la lista quedan valores volver a 1 con la lista sin el máximo
3. Se acaba.
   O sea ordenar lista(N items) = item máximo y ordenar lista(n-1 elementos) hasta que no queden elementos.

Como ves en cada repetición nos acercamos un paso al final del proceso.

Por ejemplo **sumar(desde 3 a 0)**  es 3 + **sumar(desde 2 a 0)**
**sumar(desde 2 a 0)** es 2 +**sumar(desde 1 a 0)**.
Llegas a sumar(1, 0) que es 1.
Ahí acaban las repeticiones.
Y te encuentras con
1 + 2 + 3
O desarrollado de otra forma en cada paso tienes:
3 + sumar(desde 2 a 0)
3 + 2 + sumar(desde 1 a 0)
3 + 3 + 1

Es la idea.

Tienes que probar muchos, el ejemplo más habitual es el factorial (4x3x2x1) es como la suma que te pongo. Prueba con ese ejemplo, con la ordenación...
Pero hay más como el algoritmo de Euclides para el máximo común divisor, o la búsqueda binaria en una lista ordenada (buscar en medias listas), la potencia (4 elevado a 5, es 4 por 4 elevado a 4, que es 4 por 4 elevado a 3....)
Si googleas encontrarás un montón.
Es una solución bonita y elegante en programación, pero ojo que puede comer muchos recursos.
Espero al menos no haberte liado más.

Comment: Entiendo cómo funciona la función recursiva para calcular el factorial de un número, también la de fibonacci, pero más allá de eso no entiendo nada más, por ejemplo el programa que deje en la pregunta no logro descifrar como funciona...

Comment: Me confunde el hecho de que hay 2 llamadas.

Answer (score 1):

La primera llamada te da la combinación 0000 y la segunda  mete los 1,s. Es decir a la 0000 le pone en 1 en lugar del último 0, a la 00 le pone el ultimo 1 par dar 01... .  Y solo pone el 1 en las combinaciones terminadas en 0, para que no haya dos 1,s seguidos.
Por si te sirve esta es la lista de llamadas que hace a la función recursiva con los argumentos para el 3:

```
combinaciones_binarias(3)
llamada:  num 3 Space:  last-digit: 0
llamada:  num 2 Space: 0 last-digit: 0
llamada:  num 1 Space: 00 last-digit: 0
llamada:  num 0 Space: 000 last-digit: 0
000  
num 0 Space: 001 last-digit: 1
001  
llamada:  num 1 Space: 01 last-digit: 1
llamada:  num 0 Space: 010 last-digit: 0
010  
llamada:  num 2 Space: 1 last-digit: 1
llamada:  num 1 Space: 10 last-digit: 0
 llamada:  num 0 Space: 100 last-digit: 0 
100   
num 0 Space: 101 last-digit: 1
101
```

Para un solo bit las combinaciones son 0, 1
Para dos bits tienes que añadir 0,1 a cada una de la anterior
**0**0 **0**1 y **1**0 **1**1
Para 3 bits seria lo mismo añadir 0, 1  a cada una de las anteriores
**00**0 **00**1, **01**0 **01**1
Pero en este caso solo se añade 1 si no termina en 1 para evitar la secuencia 11.
Usar la recursividad no siempre implica entender el proceso paso a paso, es dejar un poco que la máquina trabaje. Eso si, es necesario entender la mecánica del proceso.